# creating shared storage space for linux build on 32 GB USB

Tags: linux, usb, boot, formatting, storage

I'm building LFS to a 32 GB USB key and I am wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction for some information on how to format my USB key to meet the following requirements:

- when booted from, load the LFS build
- when accessed from a running computer act as USB storage

I have used cfdisk to create a 2 GB swap space and 20 GB as the boot portion. I want to use the remaining 10 GB as shared storage accessible to the LFS system and usable as USB storage.
I was wondering how I should format the remaining 10 GB so it can be used and it won't tell me to format it.

All help and direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kinds of systems you need to access the partition from.

If you only need to access it from other Linux/Unix/BSD systems, you should probably be okay with formatting it with some *ext* filesystem (I would recommend *ext4*). If you need to be able to access it from Windows systems also, you should format it with either *NTFS* or some *FAT* FS. If you want most USB capable devices to be able to use it (eg. TVs with USB ports, stereo systems, PS3 etc.), you should format it with *vfat* .